# LWC lightning data table not showing vertical scrollbar and 'sortable' not sorting - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, sort, scrolling

I have a component with a Lightning-data-table but I can't get the vertical scrollbar to show up and although, when I add 'sortable' to a column, the arrow appears but nothing happens when I click the column. It's probably a simple omission somewhere but every example I look at it just seems to have the scrollbar already there, without having to add anything to the table definition. What am I missing?

```
const columns = [
{ label: "Name", fieldName: "Name", sortable: true },
{
 label: "Membership",
 fieldName: "Membership__c",
 sortable: true
},
{
 label: "Status",
 fieldName: "Status__c",
 sortable: true
}
];
```

The table:

```
 <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-around_medium">
    <lightning-datatable
      key-field="Id"
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      onrowselection={getSelectedRecord}
      show-row-number-column
    >
    </lightning-datatable>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get the scroll bar, set the height to the parent div.

---

### Sorting

You need to add `sorted-by` value to your `datatable`.

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-around_medium">
    <lightning-datatable
      key-field="Id"
      data={data}
      sorted-by={sortedBy}
      onsort={updateColumnSorting}
      columns={columns}
      onrowselection={getSelectedRecord}
      show-row-number-column
    >
    </lightning-datatable>
 </div>
```

Also, add a method to handle `onsort`.

```
sortedBy;
// ...
updateColumnSorting(event) {
    var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    this.data = this.sortData(fieldName, sortDirection);
}
```

lastly, define the `sortData`.

```
sortData(fieldname, direction) {
    let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    // Return the value stored in the field
    let keyValue = (a) => {
        return a[fieldname];
    };
    // cheking reverse direction
    let isReverse = direction === ‘asc’ ? 1 : -1;
    // sorting data
    parseData.sort((x, y) => {
        x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ‘’; // handling null values
        y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : ‘’;
        // sorting values based on direction
        return isReverse * ((x > y)—(y > x));
    });
    this.data = parseData;
}
```

References
[Lightning Web Component Datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)
[Lightning Datatable Sorting in Lightning Web Components](https://medium.com/@amitsalesforce.com/lightning-datatable-sorting-in-lightning-web-components-a16bb408cbf#:%7E:text=Lightning%2Ddatatable,fieldName%20attribute%20on%20the%20column.)